# How to pass keyword argument to function called by concurrent.futures map call

Tags: python, dictionary, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I have the following code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def spam(url, hello=None, params=None):
    print(url, hello, params)

urls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
params = [(6, 7), 7, ('a', 1), 9, 'ab']
with ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as executor:
    res = executor.map(spam, urls, params)
```

This expectedly prints:

```
1 (6, 7) None
2 7 None
3 ('a', 1) None
4 9 None
5 ab None
```

Is there a way to tell the `map` function to call `spam` with a particular keyword argument? In this example, I'd like the values params to be passed to the `hello` argument rather then the next in line (which in this case is `params`).

The real-world use case I'm trying to solve is passing the `params=` value to a `request.get` call for a repeating URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could wrap `spam` in a lambda when doing `map`

```
res = executor.map(lambda x,y:spam(x,params=y), urls, params)
```